# How accurate are the new visualisations of V404 Cygni

Tags: black-hole, binary-star

A number of pictures and some animations similar to the ones below have had much press recently. Clearly the colours are artificial, but I wondered how accurately the represent the geometry of the system -- the relative sizes of the event horizon and the thin and thick accretion disks, the distance from the companion star, and so on.

Does anyone know.
[image]

[image]

The images are taken from popular press sites, but seem to originate from [ICRAR](https://www.icrar.org/Cygni), where they are described as "artists impressions". I would nevertheless be interested to know how accurate a brief their artists were working from.

Comment: Post sources. Otherwise no one can help you. Possibly this visualisation is the outcome of a MHD simulation, and would then represent the real system geometry, but without a source noone can say.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Source added as far back as I can trace.

Comment: The publication this article is about is an observation about the jets changing direction. So probably, as the image captions say on this website, those are just artists impressions.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Sure. But someone on here might know more from other sources.

Comment: I guess it would depend on what degree of accuracy would be acceptable, but as these are for illustrative purposes only I think it would be fair to say they are not very accurate at all.